# instanceSearch to instenceSearch react Hook

Tags: react-hooks, algolia, instantsearch.js

I am planing to move from react **instanceSearch**  to **instenceSearch react Hook**.
React instanceSearch provide allSearchResults attribute. How can I get allSearchResults for Multi indices in InstenceSearch react Hook

In instanceSearch Algolia doc had this

> [Multi indices](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/going-further/conditional-display/react/#multi-indices)#
>
> If you’re using the Index widget with conditional rendering, access
> the searchResults and the results of all indices (with
> allSearchResults).

However, this part is missing in the React InstantSearch Hooks documentation. The support team suggests using the "useInstantSearch()" hook, but I couldn't find a way to use it when performing a multi-index search.

My main requirement is to change the order of the indices in the UI based on the results count, and the first hit of all indices should have fullyHighlighted. I'm looking for a solution to prioritize those indices.

Comment: did u manage to solve this. maybe like `const { results } = useInstantSearch();`

Comment: @cmgchess solved it. Please check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is simple

```
const { scopedResults } = useInstantSearch();
```

Then you can find the index by name

```
scopedResults.find((item) => item.indexId === indexId)
```